# Need help on customizing my Odds Ratio (ggplot)!

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm assigned to create an Odds of Ratio ggplot in R. The plot I'm supposed to create is given below.

[Given plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhKmB.png)

My job is to figure out codes which creates the exact plots in R. I've done most parts. Here is my work.

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhLkn.png)

Before jumping into my code, it is very important that I am not using the correct values for boxOdds, boxCILow, and boxCIHigh since I have not figured out the correct values. I wanted to figure out codes for ggplot first so I can enter the right values as soon as I find them.

**This is the code I used**:

```
library(ggplot2)

boxLabels = c("Females/Males", "Student-Centered Prac. (+1)", "Instructor Quality (+1)", "Undecided / STM", 
              "non-STEM / STM", "Pre-med / STM", "Engineering / STM", "Std. test percentile (+10)", 
              "No previous calc / HS calc", "College calc / HS calc")

df <- data.frame(yAxis = length(boxLabels):1,
                 boxOdds = 
                   c(2.23189, 1.315737, 1.22866, 0.8197413, 0.9802449, 0.9786673, 0.6559005, 0.5929812, 0.6923759, 1.3958275),
                 boxCILow = 
                   c(.7543566,1.016,.9674772,.6463458,.9643047,.864922,.4965308,.3572142, 0.4523759, 1.2023275),
                 boxCIHigh = 
                   c(6.603418,1.703902,1.560353,1.039654,.9964486,1.107371,.8664225,.9843584, 0.9323759, 1.5893275) 
)


(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = boxLabels)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = 0.75, linetype = 'dashed') +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = 
                     0, color = 'gray50') + 
    geom_point(size = 3.5, color = 'orange') +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
    ylab('') +
    xlab('Odds Ratio') + 
    annotate(geom = 'text', y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ='', 
             size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle('Estimated Odds of Switching') + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 30), 
          axis.title.x = (element_text(size = 15))) + 
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank())
)
p
```

**Where I'm stuck at**:

1. Removing small vertical lines on the beginning and end of each row's CI). I was not sure what it's called so I was having hard time looking it up. **SOLVED**
2. I'm also stuck at coloring specific rows in different colors.
3. The last part I'm stuck at is assigning proper order of each variable for y-axis. As you can see in my code ("boxLabels" part), I have put all the variables in order of given plot but it seems like the R didn't care about the order. So the varaible located at the very top is "Undecided / STM", instead of "Females / Males".
4. How do I decrease the space from 0 to 1?  **SOLVED**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All your questions have answers somewhere on SO: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693025/remove-error-bar-ends-in-r-using-ggplot2 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph 4. simply remove coord_trans?

Comment: Question 4 worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, probably you want `ggstance::geom_pointrangeh`. Second, you could define colors by `yAxis` right at the beginning. To group some factors create a new variable `group`. Third is related to your data where you could assign factor labels. Fourth, remove `coord_trans` as suggested by *@beetroot*.

**Assign factor labels**

```
dat$yAxis <- factor(dat$yAxis, levels=10:1, labels=rev(boxLabels))
```

**Create groups**

```
dat$group <- 1
dat$group[which(dat$yAxis %in% c("Females/Males", "Undecided / STM", "non-STEM / STM",
                        "Pre-med / STM"))] <- 2
dat$group[which(dat$yAxis %in% c("Student-Centered Prac. (+1)",
                               "No previous calc / HS calc", 
                               "College calc / HS calc"))] <- 3
```

**Colors**

```
colors <- c("#860fc2", "#fc691d", "black")
```

**Plot**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=boxOdds, y=yAxis, color=as.factor(group))) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=1), size=0.75, linetype='dashed') +
  geom_pointrangeh(aes(xmax=boxCIHigh, xmin=boxCILow), size=.5, 
                   show.legend=FALSE) +
  geom_point(size=3.5, show.legend=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values=colors)+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,7,1), limits=c(0, max(dat[2:4]))) +
  ylab('') +
  xlab('Odds Ratio') +
  annotate(geom='text', y =1.1, x=3.5, label ='', 
           size=3.5, hjust=0) + ggtitle('Estimated Odds of Switching') + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5, size=20)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

***Gives***

[image]

---

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(yAxis = 10:1, boxOdds = c(2.23189, 1.315737, 1.22866, 
0.8197413, 0.9802449, 0.9786673, 0.6559005, 0.5929812, 0.6923759, 
1.3958275), boxCILow = c(0.7543566, 1.016, 0.9674772, 0.6463458, 
0.9643047, 0.864922, 0.4965308, 0.3572142, 0.4523759, 1.2023275
), boxCIHigh = c(6.603418, 1.703902, 1.560353, 1.039654, 0.9964486, 
1.107371, 0.8664225, 0.9843584, 0.9323759, 1.5893275)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I still had some questions after your answers.
For my second question, I want to assign same color for "Female/Males", "Undecided/STM", "non-STEM/STM", and "Pre-med/STM", instead of coloring all differently.
For the third answer, what did you mean by assigning factor levels?
What I meant by Question 4 was how do I make the space smaller from 0 to geom_vline. If you look at the "Given plot" and "My work", you will realize that the "Given plot" has much smaller space from 0 to the geom_vline.